# React hook: Pass grid's object to parent component

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I have a parent component which calls common grid component(child). The structure of the grid component is defined in the child component. The parent component just sends the data to the child component.

```
<Grid tableData={gridData} columnData={activeColumnDef} onselectedRows={isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect}/>}
```

Child component:

```
const Grid = ({ tableData, columnData, ...props}) => {
    const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);


const onGridReady = params => {
        setGridApi(params.api);
        setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
    }

const refreshEntireGrid = () => {
        gridApi.setRowData(gridrowData);
        gridApi.refreshCells({force:true});
  }
const getSelectedRowData = (event) => {
        props.onselectedRows(event.api.getSelectedRows().length);
 }

<div className="ag-theme-alpine-dark">
                <AgGridReact
                    onGridReady={onGridReady}
                    defaultColDef={{
                        initialWidth: 270,
                        sortable: true,
                        filter: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        sizeColumnsToFit: true
                    }}
                    ref={gridRef}
                    applyColumnDefOrder={true}
                    headerCheckboxSelection={true}
                    suppressPaginationPanel={true}
                    columnDefs={gridcolumns}
                    rowData={gridrowData}
                    pagination={true}
                    paginationAutoPageSize={true}
                    rowSelection="multiple"
                    onSelect={(event) => getSelectedRowData(event)}
                    onSelectionChanged={getSelectedRowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
```

In the parent component itself there are set of buttons. One of such buttons is RemoveButton which removes the selected rows from the grid and refreshButton that refreshes the grid. To capture the selected rows and the gridApi state, I have defined various functions.

I would like to achieve two things--

1. Either pass refreshEntireGrid function to the parent component so that when I click on the button in parent component this function is triggered.
2. Or find a way to pass the gridApi state to the parent object so that I can use it at multiple places. Instead of passing multiple methods from parent object as props, it would be more cleaner if I can pass gridApi to parent and use in whichever onClick method(in parent component) there is a need of it.

Is there a better solution instead of the two that I am thinking ? Please help ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is bit tricky. But quite easy if you understand below steps:

- Create a callback in the parent component which takes in the data
  needed as a parameter.
- Pass this callback as a prop to the child
  component.
- Send data from the child component using the callback.

**ParentComponent**

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
 let [gridValueFromChild, setGridValueFromChild] = useState(null);

 let callback = valueFromChild => setGridValueFromChild(valueFromChild);

 return (
   <div>
     <ChildComponent callbackFunc={callback} someValue={value} />
   </div>
 );
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
 const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
 
const refreshEntireGrid = () => {
        gridApi.setRowData(gridrowData);
        gridApi.refreshCells({force:true});
   // Send gridApi value to Parent
   props.callbackFunc(gridApi)
 }

// Incase you want to send data to parent at ComponentDidMount itself
useEffect(() => {
   props.callbackFunc(gridApi)
}, [])

 return (
   <div>
      ...
   </div>
 );
}
```

If u want to pass gridApi value at the beginning itself or at any state change, You can use UseEffect hook and call `callbackFunc` there

Comment: I tried both the solution you suggested. But I get props.callbackFunc is not a function error in both cases. I think useEffect one will be more applicable to me. Can you please show an example for it ? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer using useEffect. I dont underrstand how did u get callbackFunc is not a function. When I'm trying the same in my codebase. Its working. See this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2svsve?file=src/App.js